# dynamically filled forms with Jquery & Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, forms, zend-framework, dynamic

I have a bit of a problem achieving what I'm trying to do.

I'm doing a mailbox like page and I'd like to add a "Respond" button which will fill a form with some values.

I'm generating my page message by message in php. For each message I generate an input button with its own id and when I click on the button, I'd like to open a form in a new window, with the recipient and title prefilled and not changeable by the user, with another textarea that the user can fill with his message.

For that, I have a general template for a form containing 3 values (recipient, title and message). All are (for the moment) text or textarea values.

Is it possible to use one form to send a message to anyone, or do I have to generate a form for each message with pre filled values ? The last solution seems quite horrible to do.

I tried to find something that I could do with only javascript, since I want the form to be submitted asynchronously by Ajax.
I can make an onClick event and pass the values to that function, but in that case I won't have the values of the textarea the user will have entered.

Is there a way to do, for example, an entire form in Javascript with the values I'll pass through the onClick event, get the value of the textarea from the form that would have been populated with these values, and then send everything through Ajax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is what I did.

For each Respond button generated, I set an onClick event passing the fields I wanted to be pre-filled in my form to a JS function RespondMessage()

I also made a form at the bottom of my page that I hid with css.
This form contains as much hidden fields as I want pre-filled datas, and as much spans as I want to show infos.

When I call the RespondMessage function, I manually set the hidden fields in my form with the arguments I called the function with.
After that I fill my spans with the infos I want to show (for example, I set the recipient's name for my message like that).

Once all of that is done, your form is ready to be displayed. So after setting the fields in the form, I just pass the form from display:none to display:block, and do a lot of css tricks to make that smooth and beautiful.

So now you have your pre-filled form, you just need another function that will make an Ajax call to avoid reloading the page after each response, and you'll call it with the onClick event of your form's submission button.

I hope that this process will help someone.

I'm not quite sure that it's the best way to do it and I find it quite dirty and exploitable so you need a bit more server side checking than usual, but it does the job.

I don't provide code because it's mostly all really specific to the application you're setting up.